# phonegap sqlite database max size?

Tags: sqlite, cordova

What is max db size allowed using phonegap storage api?
What are the options in case the DB size will increase gradually as my users start using the app and adding data to it. ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The database size is not limited to 5MB it can keep on increasing till the phone storage is capable of handling it.

Neither PhoneGap nor SQLite limits the size of the app.

Answer (score 1):

I think 5MB WebSQL DB size limit of Chrome more information please check this group [link](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-html5/RdRe1EVRJ7Q)